# c++. compile error. am trying to add friend template function with enum template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums, friend

Please help with the next code:

```
typedef enum {a1, a2, a3} E;

template<E e>
int foo() {
    return static_cast<int>(e);
}

class A {
    A() {};

    friend int foo<E e>();
};
```

The compiler says: error C2146: syntax erorr: missing "," before identifier "e"

I would be glad if someone could explain my mistake.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want class `A` to befriend the function template `foo()`, you need to use:

```
template <E> friend int foo();
```

You can also befriend a particular instantiation of the function template `foo()`:

```
friend int foo<a1>();
```